# PHP getting full server name including port number and protocol

Tags: php

In PHP, is there a **reliable** and good way of getting these things:

Protocol: i.e. http or https
Servername: e.g. localhost
Portnumber: e.g. 8080

I can get the server name using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.

I can kind of get the protocol but I don't think it's perfect:

```
    if(strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,5))=='https') {
        return "https";
    }
    else {
        return "http";
    }
```

I don't know how to get the port number though.  The port numbers I am using are not 80.. they are 8080 and 8888.

Thank you.

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER)` and see what it gives you.

Comment: i'm using Vue CLI port forwarding locally so for me the right one was `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT']`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

You want `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` I think.

Comment: if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443')
    {
        $URL = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header("location : $URL");
        ?><script>window.location = "<?=$URL?>"</script><?
    }

Answer (score 13):

The function that returns the full protocol-server-port info:

```
function getMyUrl()
{
  $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1')) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
  $server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  $port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ? ':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] : '';
  return $protocol.$server.$port;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` will give you the port currently used.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I use:

```
    function my_server_url()
    {
        $server_name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

        if (!in_array($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'], [80, 443])) {
            $port = ":$_SERVER[SERVER_PORT]";
        } else {
            $port = '';
        }

        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1')) {
            $scheme = 'https';
        } else {
            $scheme = 'http';
        }
        return $scheme.'://'.$server_name.$port;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$services = array('http', 'ftp', 'ssh', 'telnet', 'imap', 'smtp', 'nicname', 'gopher', 'finger', 'pop3', 'www');

foreach ($services as $service) {
    $port = getservbyname($service, 'tcp');
    echo $service . ":- " . $port . "<br />\n";
}

?>
```

This is display all port numbers.

If you already know port number you can do like this,

```
echo  getservbyport(3306, "http");   // 80
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (strcasecmp('off', $_SERVER['HTTPS']) !== 0);
$hostname = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,4))=='http') {
        $strOut = sprintf('http://%s:%d', 
                       $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],
                       $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);
    } else {
         $strOut = sprintf('https://%s:%d', 
                       $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],
                       $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);
    }

 return $strOut;
```

Try something like that if you want

Answer (score 0):

nothing worked serverside , something was wrong on APACHE and I had no access to 
 the server and I ended up redirecting to http throught Javascript, It's not the ideal solution maybe this can save someone else in my situation

```
<script>
if(!window.location.href.startsWith('https')) 
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('http','https');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get server name and port number just apply this functions

";
                                            // Append the requested resource location to the URL   
                                            echo  $url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];




                                            ?>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you get full url like this

```
strtolower(array_shift(explode("/",$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'])))."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

or (If you want host name from HTTP)

```
strtolower(array_shift(explode("/",$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'])))."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392047/array-shift-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-error-in-php), if u want to use `array_shift()`, it's about strict standards.