# array_shift : Only variables should be passed by reference error in php

Tags: php

I got an error:
*Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference*

```
 $string =  array_shift(array_keys($_REQUEST));
```

How can I correct that ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$tmpArray = array_keys($_REQUEST);
$string =  array_shift($tmpArray);
```

Temporary array needed :(

Comment: But evaluation in PhpStorm works fine. [array_shift](https://i.imgur.com/h6OsxBb.png)

Answer (score 2):

Assign the result of `array_keys($_REQUEST)` to a variable and pass that variable to `array_shift`:

```
$var = array_keys($_REQUEST);
$string =  array_shift($var);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have a set up PHP to run under strict mode or it might have been the default behaviour.

Since output of array_keys($_REQUEST) is not a variable and under strict mode this will generate a warning. This behavior is extremely non-intuitive as the array_keys($_REQUEST) method returns an array value.

So to resolve this problem, assign the output of array_keys($_REQUEST)  to a variable and then use it like below:

```
$keys = array_keys($_REQUEST);
$shift = array_shift($keys);
```